# How to start Activity with pending intent and clear all backstack?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have "HomeActivity" with different fragments. I want to clear all backstack in HomeActivity when I click on pendingIntent (HomeActivity). In case any other fragment is open, It should get cleared when I click on pendingIntent.

Andoidmanifest.XML

```
<activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode = "singleTask"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Notification Intent Code is as below:

```
 Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);   //SplashScreen is first activity
                // Set the Activity to start in a new, empty task
                notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, notifyIntent , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                Common.showNotification(this, new Random().nextInt(),
                        dataRecv.get(Common.NOTI_TITLE),
                        dataRecv.get(Common.NOTI_CONTENT),
                        pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Why are you using `singleTask` launch mode?

Comment: I resolved this by adding (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); flags when SplashScreen call my main activity.

Comment: OK, but you still need to be careful about using the special launch modes like `singleTask` and `singleInstance`. In general, you shouldn't use these as they create more problems than they solve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call below method to clear all backstack

```
finishAffinity();
```